# Calculate ∂f/∂x(p) and ∂f/∂y(p)...

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:R^
2 → R$ is a continuously differentiable function such that

∂f/∂$\vec{u}$(p) = 4 and ∂f/∂$\vec{v}$(p)= 7,

where p ∈ $R^2$
is some point and $\vec{u}$ = (3, 7) and $\vec{v}$ = (2, 5).

Calculate ∂f/∂x(p) and ∂f/∂y(p).

I am unsure how I would solve this. Would I have to use some sort of u substitution or change of variables? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The system of equations you need to solve are 
$$
3\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\vec{p})+7\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\vec{p})=4\\
2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\vec{p})+5\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\vec{p})=7
$$

Comment: I ended up with ∂f/∂x(p) = -87/3 and ∂f/∂y(p) = 13.

Comment: @JackHarold that's correct

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let's use the definition of **directional derivative**

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla\cdot\vec v=v_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+v_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Shouldn't the second term be ∂f/∂y instead of ∂f/∂x?

Comment: oh yes of course! just a typo, Thanks.